# How to make a page longer than 300cm in Libre Office Writer

Tags: libreoffice-writer

The maximum page height in Libre Office Writer is limited to 300cm.

This seems somewhat of an arbitrary limit.

Is there a way to extend the page further than that?

P.S. I know about Web layout (infinite page) but it doesn't quite fit my needs.

Comment: If you need a page longer than 300 cm, it isn't a normal document.  Consider whether you might be using the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there a way to extend the page further than 300cm?

LibreOffice is [Free Software](https://www.fsf.org/about/what-is-free-software). You can

- Make a [Feature Request](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/scope:all/sort:age-asc/tags:feature-request/page:1/), or
- Download the SDK and Source Code from [LibreOffice Fresh](https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/) and make the changes yourself.